# android permission error although is defined at manifest

Tags: android, permissions

iam using a Cursor to get CallLogs and I defined a permission for it AT manifest
like this :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" />
```

but I still got an error on :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider  requires android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG or android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG
```

Comment: which emulator you are using?

Comment: did you add run time permssion

Comment: and api version for device?

Comment: Which version of the android it is ? If is Marshmallow (Android version 6.0, API Level 23) or  grater than it u need to handle the run time permissions

Comment: @NoumanCh default android studio emulator with api24 android 7

Comment: @NileshRathod yes as i said in the manifest

Comment: not in manifest file you need to ask runtime permssion

Comment: @KingofMasses a am tasting on android 7

Comment: @another.one **Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app**

Comment: yes sorry for late reply actually you need to use runtime permissions as Nilesh mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should request for the permission during runtime for android M and above. This way

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                //Show Information about why you need the permission
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,false)) {
                //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
                // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Need Storage Permission");
                builder.setMessage("This app needs storage permission.");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        sentToSettings = true;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go to Permissions to Grant Storage", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();
            } else {
                //just request the permission
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CONSTANT);
            }


        } else {
            //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
            proceedAfterPermission();
        }

//Have included an alert dialog for user to grant the permission.
```